# Shadow of RoundedRectangle is pixelated on edges

Tags: swiftui, shadow, pixelate

Based on some logic we apply shadow for RoundedRectangle which is the element used in the .background property of the whole VStack.

```
VStack { 
  ...
}
.background(
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16, style: .continuous)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: .black,
                            radius: .zero,
                            x: 4,
                            y: 4)
)
```

The pixelated parts appear on the bottom left and right edges as well as the top right corner.

I did try using different kinds of RoundedRectangle styles (both of them .circular & continuous), but nothing really helped.

Thanks in advance.